# MySQL Redash - Соединение итоговых данных 2 подзапросов в одном select

Tags: mysql

Необходимо объединить итоговые данные двух select без потери данных, которая происходит при условии выборки по where.
А именно нужно к первому подзапросу добавить итоговые данные из второго подзапроса 'Moves'

Запрос ниже выдает корректные данные, но убирает людей, которых нет во втором подзапросе (request_2), но есть в первом (request_1).
Я не понимаю как заставить второй подзапрос выводить "0" при отсутствии данных с условиями where.
Люди исключаются во втором подзапросе во время проверки where.

Пытался связать через left join.
В этом случае выводятся все люди, но данные задваиваются, а в столбце Move у всех одно и то же значение.

SUBSTRING_INDEX использую для того, чтобы убрать цифры после запятой.

Я понимаю, что совпадение нужно делать через left join request_1.user = request_2.user2 чтобы не терять данные из request_1, но как исключить дублирование значений - я не знаю.
Либо же нужно во втором подзапросе вывести всех сотрудников со значением "0" в обход where ... and ... and ... , но и тут у меня тоже ничего не получается. Я наверное куда только мог запихнуть IFNULL, но это не дает нужного результата. Хотя я не исключаю того, что добавлял его не туда, либо добавлять его нужно не только в один подзапрос.

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING_INDEX (round (request_1.1_Level + request_2.Moves), ',', 1)  as sum,
request_1.1_Level as 1lvl,
request_1.2_Level as 2lvl,
request_2.Moves as move,
request_1.user as user
FROM
(
    select
    SUBSTRING_INDEX (round (sum(th.history_type_id in (1, 2, 3) and th.queue_id NOT IN (5)) + (round(sum(th.history_type_id in (6, 7)) / 16))), ',', 1) as '1_Level',
    SUBSTRING_INDEX (SUM(th.history_type_id in (1, 2, 3) and th.queue_id = 5), ',', 1) as '2_Level',
    CONCAT(u.last_name, ' ', u.first_name) as user
    From ticket_history th
    left join users u on th.change_by = u.id
    where th.history_type_id in (1, 2, 3, 6, 7) and th.create_time between ('{{start}}') and ('{{stop}}')
    group by th.create_by
) AS request_1,

(
    select
    SUBSTRING_INDEX ((round (COUNT(DISTINCT th.ticket_id) / 9)), ',', 1) as Moves,
    CONCAT(u.last_name, ' ', u.first_name) as user2
    From ticket_history th
    left join users u on th.change_by = u.id
    left join rep_paymove rp on CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(th.name, '%%', -1), ' ', th.queue_id) = CONCAT(rp.queuefrom, ' ', rp.queueto)
    where th.create_time between ('{{start}}') and ('{{stop}}')
    and th.history_type_id = 92
    and CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(th.name, '%%', -1), ' ', th.queue_id) = CONCAT(rp.queuefrom, ' ', rp.queueto)
    group by th.create_by
) AS request_2
where request_1.user = request_2.user2
```

UPD: обновленный запрос. Нужно только вывести значение для 'only move', а именно посчитать кол-во записей по условиям(как where, но в рамках select).
Первый SUBSTRING_INDEX содержит суммарную информацию.
Третий SUBSTRING_INDEX содержит только информацию, которую как раз необходимо посчитать по условиям.
Т.е. осталось разобраться только с третьим SUBSTRING_INDEX.

```
select
SUBSTRING_INDEX (round(sum(th.history_type_id in (1, 2, 3) and th.queue_id NOT IN (5)) + (round(sum(th.history_type_id in (6, 7)) / 16)) + (round(COUNT(DISTINCT th.ticket_id and th.history_type_id = 92 and CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(th.name, '%%', -1), ' ', th.queue_id) = CONCAT(rp.queuefrom, ' ', rp.queueto)) / 9))), ',', 1) as '1_Level',
SUBSTRING_INDEX (SUM(th.history_type_id in (1, 2, 3) and th.queue_id = 5), ',', 1) as '2_Level',
SUBSTRING_INDEX (round(COUNT(DISTINCT th.ticket_id and (th.history_type_id in (92)) and (CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(th.name, '%%', -1), ' ', th.queue_id) = CONCAT(rp.queuefrom, ' ', rp.queueto))) / 9), ',', 1) as 'only move',
CONCAT(u.last_name, ' ', u.first_name) as user
From ticket_history th
left join users u on th.change_by = u.id
left join ticket t ON th.ticket_id = t.id
left join rep_paymove rp on CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(th.name, '%%', -1), ' ', th.queue_id) = CONCAT(rp.queuefrom, ' ', rp.queueto)
where th.history_type_id in (1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 92) and th.create_time between ('{{start}}') and ('{{stop}}')
group by th.create_by
```

Comment: *Я понимаю, что совпадение нужно делать через left join request_1.user = request_2.user2 чтобы не терять данные из request_1* Это правильное понимание. Но надо также понимать, что может потеряться часть данных из второго подзапроса. *В этом случае выводятся все люди, но данные задваиваются, а в столбце Move у всех одно и то же значение.* Это нормально. И правильно. Дубликат - это когда значения абсолютно всех полей совпадает, если хоть где-то различается, то это не дубликаты.

Comment: Ваш комментарий натолкнул меня на изменение логики запроса. 
Запрос стал в 3 раза меньше и это почти то что нужно, за исключением одного момента.

Пытаюсь сделать в это:
`Select 
SUBSTRING_INDEX (round(COUNT(DISTINCT th.ticket_id and (th.history_type_id = 92) and (CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(th.name, '%%', -1), ' ', th.queue_id) = CONCAT(rp.queuefrom, ' ', rp.queueto))) / 9), ',', 1) as 'move'`

Но в 'move' везде выводится 0, и как я понимаю проблема в блоке COUNT и его условиях.
Возможно ли в рамках select - DISTINCT использовать условия выборки как при where ... and ... and?

Comment: Т.е. смысл этой части запроса в том, чтобы посчитать уникальные значения _DISTINCT th.ticket_id_ по условиям выборки and...
Нужно повторить условия выборки where из 2 подзапроса изначальной логики поста.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь в своём COUNT посчитать количество (не-ноль и не-NULL) значений выражения `th.ticket_id and (th.history_type_id = 92) and (CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(th.name, '%%', -1), ' ', th.queue_id) = CONCAT(rp.queuefrom, ' ', rp.queueto))`. Вы точно именно этого хотите? да и последующий ROUND() возвращённого из COUNT() заведомо целого значения тоже понимания не добавляет...

Comment: Обновил пост. 
Да - осталось только посчитать кол-во записей, но по условиям, которые ранее использовались в where.
_да и последующий ROUND() возвращённого из COUNT()_ - Не до конца понимаю что имеется ввиду.

Comment: *Не до конца понимаю что имеется ввиду* `ROUND(COUNT(выражение))` и `COUNT(выражение)` вернут абсолютно один и тот же результат. Округлять целое  до целого бессмысленно, оно уже как бы целое.

Comment: *осталось разобраться только с третьим SUBSTRING_INDEX* Я извиняюсь, а Вы описание функции [SUBSTRING_INDEX()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) видели? у неё первый параметр - это строка, из которой надо взять подстроку, а Вы ей подпихиваете число.

Comment: Ну ладно, сервер приведёт тип, он умеет. Далее - Вы в качестве разделителя (второй параметр) подпихиваете запятую - но в числе, неявно преобразованном в строку, никакой запятой быть не может в принципе. А потому функция вернёт значение первого своего параметра, приведённое к строковому типу. Без вариантов. Так что надо сначала разобраться, зачем Вы вообще используете именно эту функцию.

Comment: Я могу ошибаться, но примерно так я представляю как должен отрабатывать запрос. https://i.imgur.com/LDrQC9B.png Заранее прошу прощения за кривую визуализацию.
(Я забыл в итоге разделить на 9, по факту в moves(он же only move) должен быть 0, т.к. 2/9=0,2)

Comment: Поправил: https://i.imgur.com/nqygq0z.png

Comment: SUBSTRING_INDEX - в моем понимании забирает итоговую строчку и возвращает все значение до запятой. Ибо при расчете, даже если итог равен целому числу, скажем 12, то в выгрузке это будет выглядеть как 12,00. _Вы в качестве разделителя (второй параметр) подпихиваете запятую_ - если там не будет этого разделителя, число не будет целым. Либо я что-то не понимаю.

Comment: Внутри **column()** `select column() from table` - возможно ли использовать условия выборки, которые применимы для условия __where ... = ... and ...__? Я не нашел примеров выборки внутри **column()**, из-за чего складывается впечатление, что это невозможно.

Comment: (1) Какая запятая? У MySQL разделитель целой и дробной части - это точка, без вариантов. Чай, не в русскоязычном Экселе работаешь. (2) **column()** - это функция. Встроенной функции с таким именем нет - значит, определённая пользователем? а если нет и такой - будет syntax error.

Comment: Но вообще весь вопрос - чистая XY-problem.

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут описывается вариант реализации full join:

http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_full_join_and_mysql.html

Comment: Пробовал UNION ALL, но там возникло еще больше трудностей в реализации необходимого результата. 
В любом случае, спасибо. Если не получится с новой логикой разобраться, то буду пытаться в UNION ALL

Comment: UNION ALL не подходит, т.к. в двух запросах Select разное вол-ко колонок, а необходимо равное кол-во. А если во второй запрос добавлять аналогичную выборку, как в первом запросе - то данные не будут верны.

Comment: добавьте во второй запрос пустые колонки